# Android Push OnClick Open Function

Tags: android, onclick, notifications, push

I want to display the data of a GCM Push Notification in my app.
I am programming natively without any framework.

1. How do I start a specific function, when a User clicks on a Push Notification? [My App just gets opened, if I click on the Notification]
2. How do I get the JSON-Data of the Push Notification?

I've been searching like hell, but most responses are for users using some framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain you problem a little more. and also paste your GCM client code, where you are facing issue. The best place for understanding this, https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: My app is receiving Push Notifications from my PHP-backend. When I click on a notification, my App just opens. What I want to do is display an AlertDialog with some information of the Push Notification.
Is there a method like onPushReceived or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for an IntentService in your code, it might be similar to this,

This should be the JSON you are interested in. You can take any action you want, add notification, create a popup etc.

Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService  {

    String TAG = "GcmIntentService";

    public GcmIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging. MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.i(TAG, extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging. MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```